# How can I access one single row of a csv file to populate my d3.js chart?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Name, Data1, Data2, Data3,...
Name_1, Data1_Value1, Data2_Value1, Data3_Value1,...
Name_2, Data1_Value2, Data2_Value2, Data3_Value3,...
```

and so forth.

Instead of plotting the data like in this [Example](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3887235)

I would like to use only the first row of data. With the Column Names as the labels.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first row is simply index `0` of the resulting data object returned from `d3.csv`:

```
  d3.csv("data.csv", function(d){
    console.log(d[0]); //<-- this is the first row
  });
```

One a side note, remove the spaces after the comman from your `csv` file, they are not necessary.

**EDITS**

You'll need to transform the data.  Simple approach is:

```
  var newData = [];
  for (var key in data[0]){
    if (key != "Name"){
      newData.push({
        name: key,
        value: +data[0][key]
      })
    }
  }
```

---

Working sample [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6S7nwIwx2BEHXL5YijpT?p=preview).

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for answering. But how would I address the data?

Comment: Hi @Marc, thank you for answering. But how would I address the data? Normally I would do something like d.population = +d.population; just as in the example. But that wouldn't work when I use data from more than one column.

Comment: @MoritzMatejka, see updates to answer above.

Comment: thank you so much. That worked perfectly. By the way the spaces in the csv were only for illustration purposes and are not actually in the file.

Comment: Would there also be a way to do this for every row in the csv file at once using the name column as an additional key creating something like [Name: Name_1[Data1:Data1_Value1]]...?